# How to make empty merge commit (ignoring changes)?

Tags: git

Automated CI tool merges fixes from `release` to `master`. But some commits from release branch should be ignored.

Let's consider the following example:

Release branch contains two fixes: `fix-1` should be ignored and `fix-2` should be merged to `master`.

```
base ----------- merge-fix-2 -        master
  \                  /            
   fix-1 --- fix-2 ---                release
```

With this configuration merge of `fix-2` also includes `fix-1` changes.

To avoid this I need *empty* merge-commit (`ignore-fix-1`), just for notify Git that `fix-1` has been already merged and these changes should be ignored in upcoming merges:

```
base -- ignore-fix-1 -- merge-fix-2 --  master
  \       /             /            
   fix-1 ----- fix-2 ----               release
```

**The question is:** how to do that `ignore-fix-1` **empty** commit?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can pass `-s ours` to `git merge` to use the "ours" merge strategy, which does exactly what you want: performs a "merge" by completely ignoring the incoming branch.

That said, this is a *surprising* thing to do to your history, to say the least.  I assume you have a compelling reason not to want a hotfix in `master`, but if this sort of thing happens frequently, you might want to consider a different approach, e.g.:

1. Split `release` into `stable` (for `fix-2`) and `production` (for `fix-1`), then frequently merge `stable` into *both* `master` and `production`.
2. Cherry-pick release fixes, rather than merging them.

Comment: Thanks, `git merge -s ours` does the trick! And thank you for advice, I will think about stable-release branch. Cherry picking as for me is a good technique, but not for the automated tool.

Comment: I wasnt to uise -s thiers but it says me "Already up to date.@

Comment: Assume "release" be the current development (the *next* release being prepared, so to say), and "master" be the current live version. Let "fix-1" be a new feature that should only go in the next release, but "fix-2" is a literal bugfix that shall be backported to the current "master" version (but the author posed a pull request to the "release" branch, because all new development goes to this ever). Then, this strategy makes totally sense. (Yes, the naming of branches in this example is odd, I would just do it the other way round, but it’s free choice.)

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways to accomplish this. Probably the simplest is to do the merge normally and then `git revert <commit ID of fix-1>`.

```
base ----------- merge-release - revert-fix-1 [master]
  \             /            
   fix-1 - fix-2 [release]
```

This has the added benefit of not re-adding `fix-1` when `release` is merged into `master` again.

The larger question is why your `release` branch has commits in it which are not to be brought back into `master`. Normally commits directly to a `release` branch are emergency hot fixes. If you need to do this only very occasionally, like for a particularly sloppy hot fix, then `git revert` is the way to go. If you plan to do this regularly, this workflow is unmaintainable and you should ask a question about the workflow itself.

Comment: Thank you for answering but for automated tool this approach does not fit well. But I agree with you, what I described is not best way to do CI

Comment: @MaxFarsikov You have to manually decide that a fix is not to be included anyway. Seems to me you can allow the automatic merge to happen as normal and then manually apply the revert after. If you want to automate the whole process you can flag a commit which is to be reverted with a special tag and teach CI to do the revert after the merge. And yes, having exceptions like this does not fit automation.